Shouldn't the integral of $1/x$ be $\text{sgn}(x)\ln|x|$?
The integral of $1/x$ across an interval $[-b,-a]$ would be the negative of the integral across the interval $[a,b]$, no? So, the equation ought to be:
$$\int \frac 1x = \text{sgn}(x)\ln|x| + C$$
Though, if we are talking about the actual area bounded between the curve of $1/x$ and the $x$-axis, then I agree the integral is merely $\ln|x|$. However, are  we not usually talking about the signed area? If so, we need to account for negative $x$-values with $\text{sgn}(x)$.

The derivative of $\text{sgn}(x)\ln|x|$ does not equal $\frac{1}{x}$, which tells you it can’t be the correct antiderivative.

Indefinite integrals are not areas, they are antiderivatives. And you seem to have forgotten that if $0\lt a\lt b$, then $-a\gt -b$, so you get another sign change.

"And you seem to have forgotten that if $0<a<b$, then $−a>−b$, so you get another sign change." Whoops, I didn't mean it like that, I will change it.

And now there is no problem! Because if $0\lt a\lt b$, then the integral over $[a,b]$ is $\ln(b)-\ln(a)$, and the integral over $[-b,-a]$ is $\ln(a)-\ln(b)$, which is precisely the negative of $\ln(b)-\ln(a)$. So what is the issue?

Well, no.  The integrand is discontinuous at $0$, so you can have different constants of integration for $x < 0$ and for $x > 0$...

@ArturoMagidin "So what is the issue?" The issue is that I am stupid xD Thank you, I see how it works now. However, the more general issue of indefinite integrals not be areas is something I am going to have to think about. It makes a little sense right off the bat, but I will have to mull it over. Thank you for the help! If you make this an answer, I will accept.

As you note, if $0\lt a\lt b$ then $-b\lt-a\lt 0$, so
$$\int_{-b}^{-a}\frac{1}{x}\,dx = -\int_a^{b}\frac{1}{x}\,dx$$
due to the fact that $\frac{1}{x}$ is an odd function. But then why would you need the sign of $x$?
$$\ln|x|\Bigm|_{-b}^{-a} = \ln|-a|-\ln|-b| = \ln(a)-\ln(b) = -\Bigl( \ln(b)-\ln(a)\Bigr) = -\left(\ln|x|\Bigm|_{a}^b\right).$$
So using $\ln|x|+C$ as the antiderivative, you get
$$\int_{-b}^{-a}\frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln(a)-\ln(b) = -\left(\ln(b)-\ln(a)\right) = -\int_{a}^b\frac{1}{x}\,dx,$$
which agrees with the geometric fact you cite: the area between $\frac{1}{x}$ and the $x$-axis over $[-b,-a]$ is minus the area between $\frac{1}{x}$ and the $x$-axis over $[a,b]$. If we included the sign of $x$, we would get equality.
The exact same argument, mutatis mutandis, works when $0\lt b\lt a$, or if they are both negative.
